# Compare how one time series affects another and which tests are needed?

Tags: regression, time-series, armax

**Context**
According to Becker (1968) and Elrich (1996) criminality study, the entrance of low income refugees with relatively lower scholarity than UK population would increase crime in the region. The main purpose of this work is analyzing if the entrance of refugees in UK statistically affected the criminality levels in UK.

**Data**
So, I have series with 52 observations, from 2003Q1 to 2015Q4, with UK's number of refugees, lots of criminality indicators like Burglary Offenses, Sexual Offenses, Robbery, and many more. Also, I know that number of police officers, gdp/capita and unemployement should affect crime. The number of refugees was converted from anually to quarterly using cubic spline method.

All the data is added here: [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uTxdHM3rWWgHtWgCEdEgql8eFBS9npzPoX5d_OuSlT8/edit?usp=sharing)

Log(Refugee) and Log(Robbery) graphs:
[image]

**Problem**
Is there a simple model that would explain how refugees entrance changed crime levels in UK? How can I avoid spurious relation among those variables?

I tried a simple ARMAX model like the one in the following image, but I suspect important variables are ommited!

[image: Eviews ARMAX Results]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your approach. You need to follow the literature in this field. They'll be considering possible controls so that omitted variable bias is taken care of, the endogeneity issues where entrance may depend on crime, conflation where the same thing is impacting both crime and immigration etc. You can't run these simple regressions and hope that someone will take this seriously, because establishing causality is very difficult in observational studies of this kind

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the literature, I already got a few good instruments that could be used to treat the endogeneity - I just don't know how to use them in the model. (Possible instruments: GDP/Capita, unemployement rates)

Comment: you should consider differences and lags, the latter also deals with endogeneity